# automatically run query from big query in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-sheets-formula

I am pulling data from Big Query into a Google Sheet.

In order to have the data refreshed, I need to open the BigQuery query editor and click on connect to  populate data into the sheet. Is it possible to automate this process? For instance every Monday at 3 am, it connects to BigQuery and refreshes the sheet?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95t9G.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the BigQuery connection automatic, go to the Data menu, select Data connectors, and click Refresh Options. Click on Scheduled refresh setup on the right panel and change the settings as follows:

Repeat every 1 week, select Monday and 3:00 AM- 4:00 AM for Repeat at and save.